# How do I retrieve two fields from a prepopulate sqlite db and assign it to custom list view?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to retrieve data from two fields from prepopulate sqlite database. The fields are Organization Name (org_name) and Contact Number (contact_no). After that I need to assign org_name data to a large text field and contact_no to small text field in my custom list view.

I have tried this only with one field. It's working fine. But when I'm trying to retrieve two fields it's not working. This is what I tried. Please help me to solve this issue.

ContactView class

```
public class ContactView extends Activity {
private ListView listView;
private ListView listView1;
List<Organization> rowItems;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);



    DBAccess databaseAccess = DBAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getQuotes(getIntent().getStringExtra("ID_EXTRA"));
    databaseAccess.close();


    List<Organization> rowItem=new ArrayList<Organization>();
    for(String quote:quotes){
        Organization temp=new Organization(quote);
        rowItem.add(temp);
    }
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.single_row_item, rowItem);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

Database Access Class

```
public class DBAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DBAccess instance;
String passedVar = null;
private ListView listView;

public DBAccess(Context context) {

    this.openHelper = new HelloDatabase(context);
}

public static DBAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DBAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

public List<String> getQuotes(String id) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer value;


    if (id != null) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT org_name,contact_no FROM org_name WHERE category_id = \"" + id + "\"", null);


        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contact_no")));
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }

        cursor.close();


    }


    return list;
}}
```

Bean class

```
public class Organization {

    public String title;
    public String telenum;

    public Organization(String title,String telenum) {

        this.title = title;
        this.telenum=telenum;

    }

    public String getTitle() {

        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {

        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTelenum(){
        return telenum;
    }

    public void setTelenum(String telenum){
        this.telenum=telenum;
    }

}
```

CustomListViewAdapter class

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Organization> {

Context context;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int layout,
                             List<Organization> items) {
    super(context, layout, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {

    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtTele;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Organization rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.org_name);
        holder.txtTele = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tele_num);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.txtTele.setText(rowItem.getTelenum());

    return convertView;
}}
```

Comment: simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: This is also working with one field. If you can please help me with this code

Comment: How are you creating `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: Is your query correct ? `SELECT org_name and contact_no FROM org_name WHERE category_id =`. It should be `SELECT org_name,contact_no FROM table_name WHERE category_id =`. First test the query in Sqlite Browser and check whether you are getting the expected results. You can also use `sqlite3` command-line utility as described at https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html

Comment: @Monish Kamble- Thank you. Yes it's a mistake of mine.But error is not that.

Comment: @pskink- I updated code with CustomListViewAdapter. Please help

Comment: dont use any `CustomListViewAdapter` when your data come from sqlite database: use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead

Comment: @pskink-But this was working with one field. Thank you .

Comment: ok so go your way, good luck

Comment: @pskink - No , actually I need guidance. Why I can't use this method to continue this? I'm a beginner. Please explain

Comment: if you are beginner than use that `SimpleCursorAdapter` and make your life simple

Comment: As suggested by pskink use `SimpleCursorAdapter`. It is easy to use. Refer the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37560755/5460053

Comment: Check my answer below and tell whether it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :** If any one facing the same issue, kindly use `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Its simple, easy to use and efficient. Find a simple example [here](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) or checkout my answer on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560755/5460053

---

It is not working for two fields because of the following lines in getQuotes() method of DBAccess class :

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));//Adding org_name first. org_name is added at indexes : 0,2,4,...
        list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contact_no")));//Then adding contact_no. contact_no is added at indexes : 1,3,5,...
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
```

Then while creating a datasource for the adapter, org_name and contact_no are added at alternate indexes

```
    List<Organization> rowItem=new ArrayList<Organization>();
    for(String quote:quotes){
        Organization temp=new Organization(quote);//I wonder how this worked as there is only one contructor for Organization which is expecting 2 parameters
        rowItem.add(temp);
    }
```

Change your DBAccess class getQuotes() to this :

```
public List<Organization> getQuotes(String id) {
    List<Organization> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (id != null) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT org_name,contact_no FROM org_name WHERE category_id = \"" + id + "\"", null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Organization org = new Organization(cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contact_no")));
                list.add(org);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

And change your ContactView Activity's onCreate() to this :

```
public class ContactView extends Activity {
private ListView listView;
private ListView listView1;
List<Organization> rowItems;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

    DBAccess databaseAccess = DBAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<Organization> rowItem = databaseAccess.getQuotes(getIntent().getStringExtra("ID_EXTRA"));
    databaseAccess.close();

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.single_row_item, rowItem);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working and I learned a lot. Thank you again.

Comment: @venura : Great! I would say you must switch to using `SimpleCursorAdapter`. It is easy to use, easy to understand, efficient that too with minimum lines of code. Or rather you must give it a try and see the difference between the two ways. Once you use it, it will be self explanatory. If you don't find it useful still you will be benefited as you would be knowing two ways for doing the same thing.

Comment: Monish Kamble, you should have said that in your answer instead of fixing OP broken code, i am afraid @venura still will be using `ArrayAdapter` approach as it worked for him...

Comment: upvote for a **Note**, i have no idea why 99% of people here insist in using `ArrayAdapter` instead of `CursorAdapter` when dealing with sqlite database